# JUnit tests SpringJUnit4ClassRunner

Tags: java, spring, junit, spring-test

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {
        "classpath:spring/integration-test.xml"
        })
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager = "transactionManager", defaultRollback = true)
public class TestClass {

    @Autowired
    private Dao dao;

    @Test
    @Transactional
    public void test1() {       

    }
}
```

Hello!
I'm trying to start single test method from Spring Tool Suite Debug configurations and I have an exception:

```
java.lang.Exception: No tests found matching [{ExactMatcher:fDisplayName=test1], {ExactMatcher:fDisplayName=test1(com.org.TestClass )], {LeadingIdentifierMatcher:fClassName=com.org.TestClass ,fLeadingIdentifier=test1]] from org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest@302e67
    at org.junit.internal.requests.FilterRequest.getRunner(FilterRequest.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createFilteredTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:77)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:43)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

But since I remove @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class) at this example the test method launched successfully.

I would appreciate any useful advice to eliminate this trouble.
Thank you.

---

I have spring version 3.1.1

Here are imports:

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionConfiguration;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
```

Comment: For the recent versions of Spring, you can use `SpringRunner` instead of `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner`.

Comment: Show your Imports please

Comment: Updated my post with spring version and imports

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is cause spring configuration specific works.
Spring created proxy instance for your class because of `@Transactional` annotation under your test method, and after that method doesn't contain `@Test` annotation.

Please see information about spring proxy there: https://spring.io/blog/2012/05/23/transactions-caching-and-aop-understanding-proxy-usage-in-spring

Do you really need `@Transactional` annotation under your test method?

You can create class-helper only for testing, write `@Transactional` annotated methods there, inject it (annotation `@Autowired`) and use in your test class

Comment: I removed @Transactional annotation and the error still  remains. It seems this is not the case.

Comment: You use junit runner and testng annotations, it’s not work. It is two different libraries

Comment: Yes, that is the reason, thanks a lot. And sorry, it was "a bit" stupid :).  A don't know how to promote your answer as correct (